# How does google know my twitter name?

Tags: google, twitter

Sometimes when i google i see this result

> Are you MyTwitterName on Twitter? If so, you can see more results like
>   this by connecting your Twitter account to your Google Account. Learn
>   more

How does google know my twitter name? I checked and it doesnt seem to be an iframe. I know sites are not able to access other sites cookies/data for exploits (stealing cookies/hijacking account but also for privacy) reasons.

So how does google know my twitter name? Is twitter making that info accessible to every site i browse (and if so how?) is google guessing by whats on my browser (referals maybe?) or using data in my gmail account?

Comment: Is your twittername the same as your gmail account name?

Comment: @paulmorriss: Pretty much. My email has a dot while twitter does not. But i may have seen it shown my friend account which is different (however his name is on his gmail)

Comment: Already closed as off-topic, but cf. [cross-posted thread at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636705/how-does-google-know-my-twitter-name) for some discussion. Also: still off-topic here. Doesn't this belong on webapps.se? (No actual "site" is being managed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done "[algorithmically](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=1142745)."
There's an expandable section under the yellow highlighted bit that provides some explanation:

> Bob, whose Gmail address is surferguybob@gmail.com, is signed in to Google and searches for [ california surf spots ]. He may see a surfing webpage shared by his friend Alice on Twitter, as well as a message asking him if he wants to connect his Twitter account, surferguybob, to his Google Account. If he confirms, twitter.com/surferguybob will be connected to his Google Account, allowing Bob to see more search results from the people he publicly follows on Twitter in the future.